# TableLayoutPanel_CellPaint() event is not firing when i invalidate()/Update() TableLayoutPanel control

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Can anyone give a solution for: `TableLayoutPanel_CellPaint()` event is not firing when I `Invalidate()`/`Update()` `TableLayoutPanel` control.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to handle the OnCellPaintevent, try overriding the OnPaint and/or OnCellPaint methods of the TableLayoutPanel Class:

```
    protected override void OnCellPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellPaint(e);

        // Your Code Here after the call to the base class.
    }
```

Also, try using Invalidate(true). The Boolean argument indicates whether the control should invalidate all of its child controls.